# Angular 2 Guards: canLoad() Is Firing Twice any Reason?

Tags: angular, angular2-guards, angular-router-guards, angular-route-guards

### canLoad Is Firing Twice On Rejection or Even In Acceptance

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'Inbox',
        canLoad: [CanActivateViaAuthGuardService],
        loadChildren: 'LazyLoaded module',
    }
]
```

### canLoad Implementation

```
canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log("CanLoad Is Called?");

    return this._apsm.IsModuleCanbeLoaded()
      .map(
      res => {
        console.log(res);

        if (res === false) {
          // User:Don't Has Access
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/error');

          return false;
        }

        // User Has Access:
        return true;
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/error');
        return Observable.of(false);
      });    
  }
```

### Servie Method Invoked

**Assuming Observale Boolean Response Will be returned**

```
IsModuleCanbeLoaded(): Observable<boolean> {         
    return false as Observable<boolean>;
}
```

Comment: Do either of your `router.navigateByUrl` calls take the user "outside" of the module? You have to be SUPER careful using redirects within route guards for this very reason. It's easy to create loops. Definitely not saying you shouldn't do it, just make sure there aren't any loops.

Comment: You could try turning on route tracing to see if it provides any clues. Add ` { enableTracing: true }` to your RouterModule.forRoot call.

Comment: more descriptive title, corrected code indenting and syntax errors

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you fix it?